# how to perform arithmetic operations and grouping and create new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert my `df1` to `df2`. They are mentioned below.

**df1:**

```
    Item    totSaleAmount   category
0   apple   10               Fruit
1   orange  50               Fruit
2   apple   20               Fruit
3   carrot  60               Vegetable
4   potato  30               Vegetable
5   coffee  5                Beverage
6   potato  10               Vegetable
7   tea     5                Beverage
8   tea     5                Beverage
9   strawberry  40           Fruit
```

df2(o/p):

```
    Item    totSale     count   category
0   apple   30            2     fruit
1   orange  50            1     fruit
2   carrot  60            1     vegetable
3   potato  40            2     vegetable
4   coffee  5             1     beverage
5   tea     10            2     beverage
6   strawberry  40        1     fruit
```

I was able to perform a few actions separately: for example, `counts` I was able to get using `value_counts()`, and `sum` I was able to perform using `sum() post filter df` with the item. But I am not sure how to put everything together and convert `df1` to `df2`.

Comment: this looks like something for [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). have a look at the link and see if it helps

Comment: yeah, but couldnt figure out , how to add up the sale amounts

Comment: Use `df1 = df.groupby(['Item','category'], sort=False)['totSaleAmount'].agg([('totSale','sum'), ('count','size')])`

Comment: This works , but when i print df1.columns , I am missing 'Item' and 'Category' , I get back only 'coun't and 'size'. Is it possibleto get all four 'Item', 'Category', 'count' and 'Size' ?